# Exception: Invalid Argument - API Weather Current Data Pull

Tags: api, exception, arguments

I'm and Old man trying to learn a new trick. 1st post. be merciful please. I keep getting this Message. Ive tried console logging it (line 13) get the same message.

All i want is to pull High low data from the openweather site for a designated city named in A2 of my spreadsheet.

The log isnt showing my API key or the location from the A2 location. ive looked at this for 2 hours and my eyes are crossing. Like i said im new. Im sure its something i have done wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
Message Exception: Invalid argument: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={location}&appid=${key} (line 14, file "Code")
```

```
function getCurrentData() { 
    //API key
    const key = "API key Here(actually a number)"
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
    const wsLocation = ss.getSheetByName("Location") 
    const wsLiveData = ss.getSheetByName("Live Data") 
    const location = wsLocation.getRange("A2").getValue()
    const highCell = wsLiveData.getRange("B4")
    const lowCell = wsLiveData.getRange("C4") 
    
    let apiURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&appid=${key}'
    //console.log(apiURL)
    const resText =    UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL).getContentText()
    console.log(resText)
}
```

Comment: The issue might be on line 12. 
Using a backtick character ( ` ) will allow you to format your strings using ${variable} syntax (template literals). The quote character ( ' ) does not do that and leaves the string as it is typed.

Comment: Demvamko AndrijaKovac your a god amongst mortals. Thank you. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears due to fetching an invalid url.
Noting in the url that syntax ${} appears, you were attempting to define the url using template literals in a normal string.
To define a template literal string you should use the backtick character ( ` ) instead of quote character ( ' ).

More information about template literals can be found here:
[Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)